# Wordpress Pagination links on Page not Found

Tags: wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming, http-status-code-404, custom-post-type

I have a little problem with my wordpress theme. So I just created a category-theme and I use following structure for my permalinks: /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/.

Pagination worked at first not, but now I've managed to make it run, finally. The links

```
             <div class="pagination">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; neuere Artikel') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('ältere Artikel &raquo;','') ?></div>
         </div>
```

are showing.

The main problem is when I click on the "next_posts"-Link or on the previous_posts-Link I'll get a 404.

Here is my code:

```
    <?
        $temp = $wp_query; 
$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query();  
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $wp_query->query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
    'paged'=>$paged
    ) );
?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="type-post">
                <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <div class="blog-date">
                    <a  class="admin" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>"><?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?></a> 
                    <a href="#" class="date"><?php the_time('j. F, Y'); ?></a> 
                    <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>" class="comments"><?php comments_number('0 Kommentare','1 Kommentar','% Kommentare'); ?></a>
                </div><!-- close .blog-date -->

                <p><? echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 100 ); ?> </p>
                <p class="alignright"><a href="blog-single.php" class="button">Read more</a></p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- END Single Content -->
         <div class="pagination">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; neuere Artikel') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('ältere Artikel &raquo;','') ?></div>
         </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

<!-- END CONTENT -->
<?php   $wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = $temp;  ?>
```

But it still does not work. Does anyone can help me with this? Thanks in advance. <3

Answer (score 2):

Go to

```
Settings -> Reading
```

and set `Blog pages show at most` and `Syndication feeds show the most recent` same as `posts_per_page` option in `wp_query->query`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

get_query_var('paged') replace with get_query_var('page')

Comment: I does not work. I changed $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; to 
  $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;, but the error still exists.

Comment: In my site
$page = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat'    => $catId, 'paged' => $page ) ); where $catId is your category id.

Comment: in what files you are using this? i tried it in archive.php, and it still wont work well. I dont get it why. Also, with your code above the link disappears.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'your post type', //Post type
            'posts_per_page' => 5, //How many post u want to display per page
            'paged' => $paged  ,
            'orderby'=> 'menu_order',                    
            );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php  while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="type-post">
                <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <div class="blog-date">
                    <a  class="admin" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>"><?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?></a> 
                    <a href="#" class="date"><?php the_time('j. F, Y'); ?></a> 
                    <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>" class="comments"><?php comments_number('0 Kommentare','1 Kommentar','% Kommentare'); ?></a>
                </div><!-- close .blog-date -->

                <p><? echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 100 ); ?> </p>
                <p class="alignright"><a href="blog-single.php" class="button">Read more</a></p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- END Single Content -->
        <?php endif; ?>
<div class="pagination">
<?php             
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
?>
</div>
```